# Is the following an affine scheme?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, affine-schemes

I need to determine whether the following is 
(i)whether $X$ is a functor;

(ii)whether it is an affine scheme;

(iii) an $R$-algebra $A$ representing $X$ and a universal element of $X(A)$.

(a) $X(C) = \{x ∈C | x^2 = 1\lor x^3 = 1\}$

(b) $X(C) = \{M ∈Mat_{2×2}(C) | M^{100} = I\}$

I think may be (a) is not an affine scheme because so far I cannot find a universal element for it... Any ideas about that?

Also I think the second one is an affine scheme. But I am not able to find its presentation because lack of computation... How to express $M^{100}=I$ in polynomials?

Comment: I don't know much about functors of points, but for (a), doesn't $\frac{\mathbb{C}[x]}{(x^2-1)(x^3-1)}$ work?  (Assuming by $C$ you mean $\mathbb{C}$, the complex numbers.)  And $M^{100}-1$ (or $x^{100}-1$) is a polynomial, isn't it?

Comment: @Quasicoherent Got it. Thanks for the comment!